# i am getting this error, misuse of aliased aggregate cost , when running this query in r studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldf

this is the code i am using inside r studio with sqldf package, please check the issue and tell how to solve this,

```
sqldf("select orders.id , firstname,   sum(item_cost * quantity_ordered) as cost
                     from orders
                     left join employees on employees.id = orders.id
                     where orders.id != 'na'
                     group by orders.id
                     having cost < avg(cost)
                     ")
```

Comment: You cant use the alias like that, you would have to do `having sum(item_cost * quantity_ordered)  < avg(sum(item_cost * quantity_ordered))`. But more importantly that would always eval to false because a number will always be greater or equal to the average of that same number.

Comment: @Igor what i am trying is, i need to filter out the records where the value of cost is less than the avg value of cost for all records

Comment: and the code u sent, its also giving the same error

as i use this code, 


sqldf("select orders.id , firstname,   sum(item_cost * quantity_ordered) as cost
                     from orders
                     left join employees on employees.id = orders.id
                     where orders.id != 'na'
                     group by orders.id
                     having sum(item_cost * quantity_ordered)  < avg(sum(item_cost * quantity_ordered))

                     ")
'''